# Is it possible to get the Next and Previous values in an SQL table when you know the Current value?

Tags: sql, mysql

What I'm trying to do is get the Next and Previous values in SQL.

In this example I'd always know the current value.

This is how my table is laid out.

| id | parentID | appID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19410 | 18371 | 2da4 | name600 |
| 19410 | 18371 | 4ac0 | name24 |
| 19410 | 18371 | 348e | name441 |

So my goal is for example get the next/previous value from the current.

So if the current is test2, I'd get test3 back.

I have looked into using offset + limit but I don't think that allows you to select a current starting point.

I cannot store an array as I don't want it to be slow either.

This differs from other questions as I do not have a iterable value as for example name won't always be test1, test2, test3.

My version is 8.0.19 - MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: If you are using MySQL, per your question, please don't tag other conflicting products. SQL Server and MySQL are *very* different (R)DBMS and use *completely* different dialects of SQL.

Comment: Rows in sql have no order, unless you specify some column to use for order in a particular query.  So there's no such thing as next or previous.

Comment: How can you identify from this table the current, previous and next rows?

Comment: @Shadow This is what makes this difficult as there is no easy  incrementing rows. The only distinct things are the UUID & Name. It would have to do something to the effect of OFFSET from a selected position.

Comment: Not possible since you cannot establish sequence of events.

Comment: @HJP22 - It is not just "difficult" - it doesn't even make sense as a requirement without something defining "next" and "previous". Any row can be returned for either next or previous as there is no natural ordering of rows

Comment: If you define "next" as the row where `name` is alphabetically the "next" then you can, otherwise your data is simply insufficient.

Comment: @MartinSmith It is possible in other versions but was wondering if it is for this. But yes it looks like the data is insufficient.

Comment: It may be possible with a Cursor.

Comment: It may be possible with a Cursor - No.. after all a cursor is built from a select

Comment: I think you are relying on a misapprehension that first in is first out and that's simply not the case..

Comment: You can use the [LEAD() window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead), but again you'd need some way of specifying the order of the rows.

Comment: Perhaps you want to change "Next and Previous values" to "Next and Previous _row_" and state what column (or columns) determine the "order" so we know how to determine "next" and "previous".

Answer (score 0):

For efficiency, you will need `INDEX(name)` (or some index *starting with* `name`)

To get the next row based on "name":

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE name > 'test2'
    ORDER BY name ASC
    LIMIT 1
```

For Previous, change 2 things:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ...
    WHERE name < 'test2'
    ORDER BY name DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

To get both  at the same time:

```
( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE name > 'test2' ORDER BY name ASC  LIMIT 1 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE name < 'test2' ORDER BY name DESC  LIMIT 1 )
```

This will be a lot faster than LEAD and LAG or Cursors.